# Vim execute command after (multiple) files loaded

Tags: vim

Is there an equivalent/workaround to the `-c` command line parameter of vim that executes a given command *after all* files have been loaded? My use case is to load multiple files in vim and show the buffer explorer list on startup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `VimEnter` autocommand. See `:help VimEnter`.

In your .vimrc:

```
au VimEnter * <call the bufexplorer function here>
```

Or specify it from the command line:

```
$ vi *.c -c "au VimEnter * BufExplorer"
```

If you use it often enough make an alias for it (assuming that you're using unix):

```
$ alias vib='vi -c "au VimEnter * BufExplorer"'
$ vib *.c
```